# Win 32 C++, Drawing a draggable rectangle to the screen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, graphics

This is a problem I've been having for a while now.  I'm trying to have a draggable rectangle to show the user an area that they've selected in my screenshot program.  The reason I want this is for users to be able to select a portion of the screen that they want to take a screenshot of.  I have tried the following method with little success:

```
void drawRect(){
HDC screenDC = ::GetDC(0);
::Rectangle(screenDC, 200, 200, 300, 300);
::ReleaseDC(0, screenDC);
}
```

Now, to give this method due credit, it does draw a rectangle to the screen in a way that I'd expect however once the dragging has stopped the rectangle persists.  I've looked at ways of getting rid of this such as updating the windows where the rectangle continues to be shown however I haven't managed to remove it.  Further to this problem since you must redraw the rectangle every monitor refresh and the rectangles persist, I am left with lots of rectangles being drawn all over the screen and I then have to mouse over or click on any windows these are drawn over to remove them.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? `GetDC (NULL)` has different behavior beginning with Windows Vista, the dimensions of that screen DC are the sum total of all monitors... in XP it is limited to the dimensions of the desktop running on the first monitor. So if the user tries to take a screenshot of a region that spans multiple monitors, the behavior is going to differ depending on your version (notably, whether they have desktop composition enabled or not). GDI is not a good code path to pursue on modern Windows anyway.

Comment: How would you suggest I go about doing this if this is a bad approach?

Comment: Windows themselves are a really good (and really portable) way of creating an opaque rectangle that can easily span multiple monitors. If you create a borderless window that you size and position at the correct location, you can avoid using GDI. It is not that GDI is a bad approach to this issue *per-se*, but it is deprecated for sure and drawing a rectangle using GDI and the "screen's Device Context" that spans multiple monitors can require a little bit of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Use DrawFocusRect instead. Drawing the same rect again removes it from the screen.